# SQL Dynamic Pivot Table Column Order

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I have a dynamic pivot table in ms sql server.
The column names are dates and appear in random order.
I would like to order the dates(columns) so they appear chronologically, the oldest being first and the most recent being last so I can trend the data by date.
I cannot figure out how to order the columns.
The date variable name is chartaccessdate.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code

```
declare @columnnames nvarchar(max)=''       
declare @sql nvarchar(max)=''
select  @columnnames += quotename(chartaccessdate) + ','
from (select distinct chartaccessdate from #temp ) as s 

set @columnnames=left(@columnnames,len(@columnnames)-1) 
set @sql=   





'select * from (

select --phase, 
unit,OccupationCode occode
,OccupationCode , chartaccessdate from #temp


) as a 

Pivot


( count(OccupationCode)
      FOR [chartaccessdate] IN (
      '+@columnnames +
      '
 -- "2021-08-23"
 --,"2021-08-24"
 --,"2021-08-21"
 --,"2021-08-22"
) )as pvt '
  

 execute sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: You shouldn't use variable coalescing `select  @columnnames +=` to aggregate, it's unreliable. Instead use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML`.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68089/how-to-use-coalesce-with-multiple-rows-and-without-preceding-comma. You should also use `QUOTENAME` to safely inject the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `SELECT DISTINCT`, one quick option would be:

```
select top 1000 chartaccessdate from #temp group by chartaccessdate order by 1
```